# Handling Notifications - Vibrations / Screen / Tones?

Tags: notifications, htc-one

My HTC One seems to vibrate for every damn notification that comes on.  When it does this, the screen does not come on and there's no sound.   I know how to turn notifications off, but I"m trying to figure out how define when a notification :

a) Turns on the screen so I can see the notification without having to turn the phone on, go to the notifications screeen, etc.

b) Provides a audio notification / tone

c) Does or does NOT vibrate

Personally, I find the vibrate with no sounds and no screen to be the most annoying.

Comment: One other comment.   Is there a way that I can defined what shows up in the notification bar without turning off all notifications?  For example, I run a software called "PlaceMe".   In the notification settings, it shows "PlaceMe is running".  I want to be able to receive notifications from it, but I don't want the "PlaceMe Is Running" to permanently take up real estate in my notifications center".

Comment: You can turn off notificatioins / vibrate / ring tone for each individual app, or go into Applications > <your app> and turn off notifications altogether. There is no system wide 'turn off notifications etc' in Android. Still. It's dumb, and annoying, but that's how it works on Android.

Comment: Most applications itself will contain these settings...

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on my HTC One M8

First Go to Settings, then go to Accessibility, and click Notification Reminder to Off

http://www.reddit.com/r/htc/comments/2w3op7/htc_one_m8_lollipop_notification_constant/

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have priority interruptions only. You can change your priorities here.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

You can also disable notifications, so your phone won't buzz.

[image: IMG: Uncheck 'Show notifications']